# NCV7751 SPI based low side relay driver IC not working

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, spi, relay, firmware

I am trying to illuminate LEDs using NCV7751 IC over SPI. I kept baud rate of 5 Megabit/second as datasheet mention
[image: image from its datasheet]

SPI is working fine, I tested it already. All the pins are connected correctly I double-checked.

[image: image shows my firmware that I expect to illuminate 8 LEDs]

0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff is received back every time.

Does anyone know what can I do to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Glad you worked out the cause of your problem. Small note for next time: please don't paste in images of your code, add the code itself! 
 http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I found the issue, pin 24 needed 5v and I had 3.3v connected.